# CameraX - Unable to configure camera 0

Tags: android, android-camerax

I use this code in MainActivity to get camera preview in real life

When the app started, the previewView is black

Based on [this code](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#3) from android documentation

```
mCameraProviderListenableFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this.requireContext());
    mCameraProviderListenableFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = mCameraProviderListenableFuture.get();

            Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
            mPreviewView.setScaleType(PreviewView
                    .ScaleType
                    .FIT_CENTER);
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(mPreviewView.getSurfaceProvider());

            CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                    .build();

            Recorder recorder = new Recorder.Builder()
                    .setQualitySelector(
                            QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST)
                    ).build();
            mVideoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder);

            cameraProvider.unbindAll();
            Log.d(TAG, "startCamera: binding to lifecycle...");
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    (LifecycleOwner) this.requireContext(),
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    mVideoCapture);

        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this.requireContext()));
```

but I gave this error in console

```
E/Camera2CameraImpl: Unable to configure camera 0, timeout!
```

permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Could you check if it works for you with some newer version of CameraX (https://stackoverflow.com/q/73451099/8019153)?