# CameraX TimeoutException Cannot complete surfaceList

Tags: android, android-camerax, android-developer-api

I am going through the CameraX tutorial at Android Developers https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#3 using version 1.1.0 of the library. The logs look good at first, but later a TimeoutException is raised and the camera preview remains black:

```
(omitted)
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
Camera                                       State                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Camera@f35a3d7[id=0]                         OPEN                  
Camera@e46a673[id=1]                         UNKNOWN               
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null
D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null}
D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-c7727ae2-d02c-4135-956c-a76c24deb02d40667318] for camera: 0
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-c7727ae2-d02c-4135-956c-a76c24deb02d40667318] for camera: 0
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f35a3d7[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENED --> OPENED
D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=StateError{code=4, cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot complete surfaceList within 5000}} from OPEN and StateError{code=4, cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot complete surfaceList within 5000}
D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=StateError{code=4, cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot complete surfaceList within 5000}}
```

My virtual hardware is Pixel 4 API 30, my Samsung A52s behaves in the same way. The code is the same as in the above tutorial, but in Java.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: same with v. 1.2.0-alpha04

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: well, looks like it was some bug of that specific library version.

Comment: @m_OO_m Do you mean that you changed the library version and it started working?

Comment: @AdamGłowacki exactly

Comment: @m_OO_m Which version worked for you? I tried with v1.2.0, v1.3.0-alpha01 and v1.3.0-alpha02 but it's not working with any of them.

Comment: @AdamGłowacki if you stick to the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#1) and use that version (1.1.0-beta01) - it will work. My current setup is:     `'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha02', 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-alpha02', 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-alpha02', 'androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-alpha02', 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha02', 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.0-alpha02'`

Comment: @m_OO_m I had no luck :( Not working with any version I tried, including 1.1.0-beta01. Nonetheless I would suggest you post what worked for you as a reply. Maybe it could help others? Also, possibly we could see for how many people it worked (number of votes).

Comment: @AdamGłowacki here's a working [example](https://github.com/stud0709/OneMoreSecret/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/onemoresecret/QRFragment.java).

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability that this is because the contents of setContentView were not modified when setting binding.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
}
```